# Evaluate the limit of ratio of sums of sines (without L'Hopital): $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x+\sin3x+\sin5x}{\sin2x+\sin4x+\sin6x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Limit to evaluate:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cfrac{\sin{(x)}+\sin{(3x)}+\sin{(5x)}}{\sin{(2x)}+\sin{(4x)}+\sin{(6x)}}$$

Proposed solution:
$$
\cfrac{\sin(x)+\sin(3x)+\sin(5x)}{\sin(2x)+\sin(4x)+\sin(6x)}
\Bigg/ \cdot\ \cfrac{1/x}{1/x}\Bigg/=
\frac{\cfrac{\sin(x)}x + \cfrac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \cdot 3 + \cfrac{\sin(5x)}{5x} \cdot 5}
{\cfrac{\sin(2x)}{2x} \cdot 2 + \cfrac{\sin(4x)}{4x} \cdot 4 + \cfrac{\sin(6x)}{6x} \cdot 6}
$$

Using $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}x=1$, we get
$$\frac{1+1\cdot 3+1\cdot 5}{1\cdot 2+1\cdot 4+1\cdot 6} = \frac 9{12} = \frac 3 4$$

Please tell me if I am correct.

Comment: sin2x=2sinxcosx seems to make it more complicated...

Comment: Yes@user271948,you have done it correctly! I don't know why you've been put on hold.You have just used the standard limit $sinx/x$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to zero.So you didn't use L'hospital rule.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming!! =) @kilimanjaro

Comment: @user271948, I've edited according to your remark, though I'm not sure if this is visible to you. How's that?

Comment: @user271948: Also, it would be slightly shorter if you first prove the limit $\lim \ \sin(ax)/x = \lim \ a\cdot \sin(ax)/ax = a$ for arbitrary $a$. Then there's no need for any cancelling, you get your limits straightaway.

Comment: @eudes Yes.  That was precisely the point of the "HINT" I provided. +1 for your comment!

Answer (score 11):

**Hint**:

$${f(x)\over g(x)}={{f(x)\over x}\over{g(x)\over x}}$$

Comment: 3/4???! I tried lim x->0 sinx/x = 1

Comment: @user271948, try editing your question to include more of the steps by which you arrive at $3/4$.  If you have doubts about the correctness of what you've done, ask it there.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

$$\sin (ax) =(ax)+O(x^3)$$

as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Why the down vote??

Comment: Maybe some people just hate asymptotic expansions because they are scared that all their favourite tools become useless. =) Anyway just to make sure no one can fault your answer, you should add "as $x \to 0$".

Comment: @user21820 Thamks!  Amf +1 for your suggestion.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$\sin(a-2)x+\sin(ax)+\sin(a+2)x$$
$$=\sin(ax)+[\sin(a-2)x+\sin(a+2)x]$$
$$=\sin(ax)[1+2\cos2x]$$

Answer (score 2):

Use 
$$
2·\cos x·\sin(kx) = \sin((k+1)x)+\sin((k-1)x)
$$
or
$$
2\sin(x/2)\sin(kx)=\cos((k-1/2)x)-\cos((k+1/2)x)
$$
or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The method in the current version of the question is correct.

I suppose to be a bit nitpicking, one might add that in things like
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}
$$
one should note that as $x\to0$, one also has $3x\to0$.  Then one has
$$
\lim_{3x\to0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} = \lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin u} u = 1.
$$